# Convert Date Time format in XML using XSLT from DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM/PM (or HH:MM:SS) to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

Tags: xml, date, xslt, time, transformation

I need an XSL code template that when I call it converts the given XML date tag from the format  DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM/PM ( - or HH:MM:SS - time can either be in 12 hour or 24 hour format) to the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.
Below is the sample XML:

```
<CSV>
    <Row1>
        <Set>Ready</Set>
        <Id>14545</Id>
        <Tile>A</Tile>
        <M>10:00:00:00</M>
        <Duration>00:00:21:24</Duration>
        <DateTime>11/2/2021 14:31</DateTime>
        <EndDateTime>18/03/2021 2:31:23 PM</EndDateTime>
    </Row1>
</CSV>
```

I want the above "DateTime" to be converted as below:

...

```
<StartTime>2021-02-11T14:31:00.000</StartTime>
<StartDate>2021-05-11T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
```

...

The DateTime can also be in 12 hour format, e.g.

```
<DateTime>18/03/2021 3:13:45 AM</DateTime>
```

to be converted to

```
<StartTime>2021-03-18T15:13:45.000</StartTime>
```

So both cases must be handled if the input time is 24 or 12 hour format.

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?